# how to unit test a variable that generates an id randomly

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Good morning people I have the following code that I am trying to carry out a unit test

```
<div *ngIf="primaryLabel" class="po-widget-footer">
    <div class="po-widget-xl" *ngIf="!secondaryLabel">
      <a class="po-widget-action" id="primaryAct[{{ id }}]" (click)="runPrimaryAction($event)">{{ primaryLabel }}</a>
    </div>
```

```
  it('should have been clicked in primary action', () => {
      spyOn(component.primaryAction, 'emit');

      fixture.detectChanges();

      const link = nativeElement.querySelector('?????'); //code here

      spyOn(eventClick, 'stopPropagation');

      link.dispatchEvent(eventClick);

      expect(component.primaryAction.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
      expect(eventClick.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a custom `id` within your HTML element and test it like this:

```html
<div class="po-widget-xl" *ngIf="!secondaryLabel">
  <a 
   class="po-widget-action" 
   [attr.my-id]="'someUniqueId'"
   id="primaryAct[{{ id }}]" 
   (click)="runPrimaryAction($event)">{{ primaryLabel }}
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
//...
const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[my-id="someUniqueId"]');
//...
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion colleague, but when using this way it points to an error in my 'dispatchEvent"
saying: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')